# Should one include the RTT measurements from retransmits in running average for RTT?

Tags: tcp

I have seen that in a TCP uses previous measurements of round trip time to estimate a round trip time and this estimate is used to compute a timeout time. I was wondering, should the round trip times for retransmitted packets be included in the estimate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A retransmitted segment has got its own timer and doesn't re-use that of the presumed lost segment. There's no reason to not use the RTT measured by it.

Answer (score 1):

In RFC 1122 (ch 4.2.3.1), first part of Karn's Algorithm says that the measured RTT of retransmitted segments *must* be ignored for computation of the smoothed RTT.

RFC 6298 (ch 3) updates this behavior by authorizing retransmitted segment with TCP timestamp option, to be used for computation of SRTT, since it removes ambiguity.

TCP Timestamps are not mandatory, they are used by default in *BSD and Linux. But, in Windows OSes, they are used if the peer uses them when initiating a connection.

Comment: But if I was to use the retransmitted segment RTT, would that even make a significant difference to the estimate?

Comment: Well, the purpose of smoothed RTT estimator is to have the best possible knowledge of the network conditions. So if you take that RTT measurement of a retransmitted segment (without timestamp) into account, you take the risk to alter your estimator and make bad decisions for further retransmissions.